# font-awesome, одинаковый размер у фона

Tags: html, css

Доброе утро!
Как сделать одинаковый размер у фона у иконок FA?

Нужно чтобы фон имел фиксированный размер 10x10px

Сейчас это дело выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.top {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #99c6e3;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href=""><i class="fa top fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href=""><i class="fa top fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href=""><i class="fa top fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href=""><i class="fa top fa-odnoklassniki" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href=""><i class="fa top fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href=""><i class="fa top fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href=""><i class="fa top fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделать ширину фиксированной и выравнивание текста по центру

```css
.top {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #99c6e3;
  padding: 10px 0;
  width: 36px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a href=""><i class="fa top fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href=""><i class="fa top fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href=""><i class="fa top fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href=""><i class="fa top fa-odnoklassniki" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href=""><i class="fa top fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href=""><i class="fa top fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href=""><i class="fa top fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```